# Reverting back to previous SSH public key

Tags: git, github, ssh, gitlab

I have two accounts I work on, one is on GitLab and the other on GitHub. I was all set and well using SSH on GitLab but then I wanted to push some stuff for GitHub and so I followed a step-by-step instruction for SSH setup on GitHub and forgot about the matter. Now as I am trying to push to the old GitLab repository, its giving me the following error

`Permission denied (publickey).fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`
`Please make sure you have the correct access rightsand the repository exists.`

Comment: Make sure you have the ssh public key registered and have your private key available locally (installed in your ssh-agent).  If you accidentally deleted/overwrote your gitlab private key when you created a new one for github, you'll need to change gitlab to use that new public key (or create yet another pair and use that -- being careful to not destroy your existing private key(s)

Answer (score 0):

Check the content of your `~/.ssh` folder. If you have only one id_rsa(.pub) key pair, that means you have overriden your GitLab key with the one generated for GitHub.

Re-generate one for GitLab:

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -f gitlab
```

Register `gitlab.pub` content to your GitLab SSH settings.

Add a ~/.ssh/config file with:

```
Host gl
  Hostname gitlab.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab
```

And change your remote URL with:

```
cd /path/to/local/gitlab/cloned/repository
git remote set-url origin gl:<me>/<myGitLabRepo>
```

Comment: in the .ssh folder i found an id_rsa(.pub) paur and another id_ed#bunch_of_numbers#(.pub) pair. Do I still have to regenerate?

Comment: Oh also there's a file called known_hosts and it has the gitlab site, the IP and the public key i guess in its entries. Github is also there.

Comment: I am trying to tamper with the config file and its all messy now, is there a way to reset the whole thing? a way to remove all these keys and start fresh?

Comment: @RetroCausalElectron You can leave your known_hosts as is. But regenerate et register a new key for GitLab, as specified in the answer. You can backup your config file, and restart from scratch with the content I mention in the answer.